# Original image getting compressed in website

Tags: html, image

I've an original image which is shown [here](http://postimg.org/image/wvoh280st/). This is a HD image which is saved as `jpg` format. `jpg` is a `lossy` format which compresses the image when loaded on websites. So I saved the image as `.png` and tried to view it in my website, but the image was blurred. I even increased `dpi` of the image in paint.net, but the image was still blurred in my website.
Here is a screen shot of my website:
[image: ing]
I want HD image to be shown in website without any blur. How can I do it?

Comment: Get bigger image (width+height). Original image is 600px × 212px and in your site (slideshow) it is stretched up to 1,140px × 404px. It is impossible to avoid blur in situations like this - proportional resizing from big to small - gives better/expected results.

Comment: Proportional resizing? How can I do it?

Comment: @AjayKulkarni: he means resizing bigger image to smaller; lke width of 1400 to 1140 px and whatever height calculates from original image ratio.

Comment: You need to **find** a larger version of that image. Do not attempt to enlarge the one you have though.

Comment: newImageHeight = (desiredImageWidth / originalImageWidth)  * originalImageHeight ... Proportional resizing, from bigger to smaller.

Answer (score 5):

**Start with a higher resolution original image**

I assume you are working from the similar looking template image, and the smartphone's screen has been added in after? The original image you linked to is only 600x212 pixels which is a very small size to work from (smaller than many mobiles, iphones and tablets). You need to start with a much larger and higher resolution image, and shrink it down as needed. Starting with a smaller image and increase the resolution or dpi cannot increase the quality since no extra details are added - often this just makes images worse.

[This image](http://blog.placeit.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/default_IMG_2173_wide_base.jpg) is the same background but slightly larger at 850x300. Any editing like adding the app's image should be done at this larger resolution (it can easily be shrunk later but this will keep the quality as high as possible). [Placeit.net](https://placeit.net/#!/stages/iphone-6-mockup-template-at-a-movie-theater-a4501) sells the 1920x1440 version of the image for only $8 which should be large enough and scale down well.

**JPG vs PNG**

JPG is designed for photos and doesn't lose much, PNGs can be too large which affects load times, which are very important for mobile users. A high resolution JPG is the best approach [examples and explanation](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/png-vs-jpg). Every separate edit made to a JPG reduces the quality a little, so starting with the largest resolution image and doing a single edit is best. The resizing can be left to the web browser and responsive CSS.

**Responsive CSS**

This allows you to use the same HTML for both desktops and different sized mobile devices, with minimum changes which are controlled by a separate CSS file. Bootstrap and foundarion are the most population. Effectively you keep the key images at their largest size, then add [media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/media-queries/infothe) to the CSS to check size of the mobile device or desktop and adjust sizes accordingly. Images can also have their size specified in relative units, eg percentages. This css-only resizing is fast and efficient.

[Google's image optimization guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization) covers [lossy vs lossless](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization#lossless-vs-lossy-image-compression), tools for fine tuning, scaling images and more. This points out that lossy/raster image formats are fine for very complex images like photos since human eyesight cannot perceive every detail anyway. What is 'lost' from the image is not normally noticable to the human eye - presuming of course you start with a high quality image.

**Other options: progressive jpg and base64**

Progressive JPGs appear to load faster than JPGs because they initially load in a way that looks like a lower quality image and then increases in quality, see [example](http://www.webpagetest.org/video/compare.php?tests=130125_0D_KZ3%2C130125_NH_KZ8&thumbSize=200&ival=100&end=full).  Base64 is mostly used for small images like icons and 'above the fold' images that need to load quickly, although they can be demanding on memory. The image is stored using a very long alphanumeric string embedded in your CSS or webpage code rather than as a separate file. [More details here](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2013/02/22/a-picture-is-worth-a-thousand-words/)

Comment: This is more sensible than previous answer. I'm going to try those options, if they work out, then I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Frist you must ensure you original picture is clear enough and have high dpi

Second you must notes that nowadays the smartphone screen definition is much higher than common PC, so your picture must have enough definition.

Third, your cellphone browser mustn't have cloud speeding. Some cellphone like Opera may lead to image compression.

At last, I recommend you use high-quality jpg format image. You must keep a balance between size and definition.

Comment: do you have a reference for the smart phone definitions being much higher than a common PC? I'd be surprised if that was the case especially when images have to be shrunk to be displayed.

Comment: Apple phones with retina have dpi around 400 or something, xiaomi and samsung at 500 or something, but i have tested many images and saw absolutely micro ammount of difference in quality as our eyes can't go beyond those pixels. So its fine if you provide a 30% larger resolution image with 72 dpi to phones.

Answer (score 0):

I would come straight to the point:

---

PNG image or JPEG if forced to resize over its current form will produce lower quality output. Best way is to use 1600px wide and whatever length image you have and use image optimization softwares such as OptiPNG, PNGQuant or XnView and compress the output image to gain substantial ammount of compression.

**Something about dpi**

It won't affect too much for desktop browsers, and meanwhile if yu have an image with initial dpi of 72, there will be no gains to put image over 72 dpi after it.

**The solution i use**

Most of the time, we work on illustrator for graphics, so we build SVG from them. SVG is scalable till the end of screens, no loss of quality at all. As far as PNG and JPEG are concerned it is much better to use larger dimension image and compress it will tools. There is one great online tool for this stuff [Kraken](http://kraken.io)

**One beautiful Trick**

In photoshop, gimp: try sharpen your image. Sharpening will increase edge contrast and you can hack around from bad surce image too.

As far as base64 is concerned, it is bad idea to put an HD image of around 110 KB's in code, every time user open's your site will get your 110KB wasted, let them be stored in cache through either `css: .class{background:url('image'); position:cover;}`.

The only way to get better results is by minimizing http request but that is too much of headache. As only method right now is too make a [image sprites](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an HD image then you should download an HD image and edit it in Photoshop where you can solve all your requirements bcoz it's the way it goes in industries.